# How to check if my Excel COM Add-In is loaded after a new workbook is created using C#?

Tags: c#

I am doing some Excel Add-In Programming using C#.

I would like to know how to check if my Excel Add-In is loaded after a new workbook is created.

Could anyone provide me a code snippet?

Comment: Well VSTO add-ins are visible under **File.Options.Add-ins**.  Where are you planning on using this detection code?  No point adding it to your add-in and I'm not sure if VSTO are accessible outside of Excel. Any code to show?  _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: Thank you for your question. Right now I do not have any code, my requirement is to check whether my Add-In is loaded or not? If the Add-In is loaded then I will perform further actions. I googled for excel Add-In checks and did not find the required answers.